# Have Facebook comments on others walls show on mine(New Facebook)

Tags: facebook

I had a setting so that my comments on other's walls would not show on my own.

Now I'd like to change it back so my comments show up on my 'timeline' but the instructions for doing so that I find online all seem to be outdated.

Is it even possible?